# React-Admin: Why the non-descriptive class names?

Tags: reactjs, selenium, webdriver, react-admin

> I am hoping someone can shed some light on what is likely a very basic `react` question.

**Within `react-admin`based web apps, is it typical/expected to see `class names`(below)?**

```js
class="jss136 jss138 jss125 jss127"
```

I am working on a project to setup some `e2e` framework using `selenium` for a `react-admin` site and it has proven to be challenging therefore I am curious if this is fairly typical to see in `react-admin` or if there may be something our development team could do differently that would provide more descriptive class names for interacting with elements?

Any information/insights into this or other tips you may have related to `e2e` testing with `selenium` within `react-admin` would be much appreciated.

Thank you,
Bob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> True Story, `react-admin` depends on `@material-ui`.
>
> And `@material-ui`'s styling solution uses `JSS` at its core.

Material-UI says that, "[class names generated by our styling solution are non-deterministic](https://v1.material-ui.com/customization/css-in-js/#jss)."

Owing to that, `@material-ui` implements optimizations for `development` and `production`.
The `classnames` are easy to debug in `development` and as short as possible in `production`.

- development: `.MuiAppBar-root-12`
- production: `.jss12`

Btw, If you don't like this default behavior, you can change it.
[JSS relies on the concept of class name generator](http://cssinjs.org/js-api/#generate-your-own-class-names).